# Use of mathematical induction to compute $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n+1}xdx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, induction

We are given a reduction formula for $\int \sin^n xdx$, namely
$$\int \sin^nxdx = -\frac{1}{n}\sin^{n-1}x\cos x + \frac{n-1}{n}\int \sin^{n-2}xdx.$$
I know how to derive this reduction formula. How can we use this formula and mathematical induction to show that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}xdx = \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{7}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2n}{2n+1}?$$
I am confused as to what the base case should be, and whether strong or "normal" induction would be a better approach.....?

Comment: http://goo.gl/DTydlP

Comment: Can you get as far as showing $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}xdx =\frac{2n}{2n+1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-1}xdx$?

Comment: @DavidH, yes I can!